# How to "Go to definition (F12)" of external code in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a c# solution A in my Visual Studio 2010. I have added a dll of solution B as a Reference. I have built solution B with "Debug".

If I run solution A in debug mode I can debug into solution B (Step Into F11) and see the code. That's nice. If I am NOT in debug mode and I "Go to definition (F12)" of external code Visual Studio opens a file without the body/logic of the methods :-( It looks something like an Interface.

Is it possible to "Go to definition (F12)" of external code in edit mode? Do I need a plugin?

I do not want to edit the external code. I just want to read the logic and set breakpoints.

Comment: Take a look at [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/)

Comment: Why not instead of adding the DLL, add the the project B to to Solution A and reference that instead ?

Comment: 1. project B stands for more than one project.

Comment: If I have more than one project to reference I think it would blow up the whole solution? And If I commit the references to the repository all team members are affected I think.

Comment: I have this same Q.  Also see [Get class source code instead of Metadata in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7853900/590956)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio: Debugging a referenced DLL, I have source in another SLN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546703/visual-studio-debugging-a-referenced-dll-i-have-source-in-another-sln)

Answer (score 0):

This situation only happens in non-Debug modes. It's better to run both in Debug when you are going to debug and set breakpoints.

Run both in the Debug mode.