# Visual Studio ignores breakpoints in different file

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I'm debugging .Net Core in Visual Studio, and the breakpoints are working fine in the current file, but when a method from a different file is called, its breakpoints aren't being hit. I'm not familiar with Visual Studio because I usually debug in VS Code so I'm sort of lost.

I've googled it, but can't find any info - is it possible that VS ignores breakpoints in files other than the current one?

(It's ignoring the `Debug.WriteLine` I added as well but I just need to confirm if it's really not hitting breakpoints rather than not actually calling the method.)

Comment: are you using mixed managed and unmanaged code? In that case you must select debug mode as mixed, otherwise it won't break

Comment: um... how do I do that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-in-mixed-mode?view=vs-2019

Comment: Did you use an old project? What is the type of different file or just as phuclv said, a c# project references a c++ dll? If not, please try to delete `bin`, `obj` file and then cpy the dll and pdb into the output folder from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546703/visual-studio-debugging-a-referenced-dll-i-have-source-in-another-sln). Please let us know if it does help.

Answer (score 0):

> Visual Studio ignores breakpoints in different file

If this issue is as phuclv's descroption, a net core project references a c++ Dynamic link library, you can follow [the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-in-mixed-mode?view=vs-2019), open the c++ project-->change it as `mixed` and then open net core project, choose `Enable native code debugging`. Also,

If you create the project in vs-code and then migrate it into VS2019,since vs-code is different from visual studio, you should try these steps:

**1)** delete the `bin` and `obj` folder first

**2)** make sure that these two options are checked under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Nuget Package Manager`.

[image]

**3)** Try disabling `Just My Code` under `Tools`--> `Options` --> `Debugging`-->`General`

**4)** If the file is from the other project,please add reference to these projects by Right-click on the `Dependencies`-->`Add Reference`-->these projects or just copy these projects's dll and pdb files into the main project's output folder(`Bin`).

**5)** Use `Debug` mode to debug your project.

**In addition**, if these do not work, please try to create a new net core project in vs and migrate your old project into the new project to test whether this issue persists.